# Centering a Linear Layout Horizontal and Vertical

Tags: android, android-layout

Im running into a speed bump in my android App. I want to center my Linear Layout in the center of the screen (Horisontally only) and I want to center another element only vertically. I haven't seen an easy apparent way to do this in the program.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfMBD.png

I want the grey Box to be centered horisontally in the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, how your layouts are now, but I'd do something like this:

- Vertical Linearlayout

  - RelativeLayout, centered horizontally
  - RelativeLayout, set to `match parent`

    - RelativeLayout, centered vertically

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` as a root `ViewGroup`, and then just add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to your first `LinearLayout`, and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to your second one.